# Decoding Text in .py file

Tags: android, python

I've a file in .py format and it contains list of cities. How can I decode it in Php. I'm letting users search for a city in my Android app and the search query will come to my server where the searched string will be matched with one of the city from the list.

```
 BusCity = {
'14TH MILE STONE': '14TH MILE STONE',
'AACHARA': 'AACHARA',
'AADSAR': 'AADSAR',
'AAHOR': 'AAHOR',
'AAMBUR': 'AAMBUR',
'AANJAR': 'AANJAR',
'AASIND': 'AASIND',
'AASPUR': 'AASPUR',
'AASTRA': 'AASTRA',
'AATHANKARAI': 'AATHANKARAI',
'AATOOR': 'AATOOR',
'AATTHUR': 'AATTHUR', }
```

And, there's another list same in .py file which contains list of airpots.

```
  AAB_dict = {'city': 'Arrabury', 'code': 'AAB', 'worldareacode': '802', 'country': 'Australia', 'longitude': '141.0', 'latitude': '-26.75', 'airportname': 'Arrabury', 'gmt': '+10.0'}

  AAE_dict = {'city': 'Annaba', 'code': 'AAE', 'worldareacode': '500', 'country': 'Algeria', 'longitude': '8.0', 'latitude': '36.83', 'airportname': 'Les Salines', 'gmt': '+1.0'}

  AAZ_dict = {'city': 'Ambriz', 'code': 'AAZ', 'worldareacode': '127', 'country': 'Angola', 'longitude': '13.1', 'latitude': '-7.85', 'airportname': 'Ambriz', 'gmt': '+1.0'}
```

How can I decode this structure so that I get the name of the city and country.

Comment: Create a python file that includes that one, and outputs those in JSON format.  Then execute that file from PHP.

Comment: Hey, how to output those in JSON format?

Comment: Put 'python json' into google and click on the first link.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.py` files are simply python files with your data in variables.

Ideally, you will want to import the data into a database (look into MySQL/Mongo). You can then have a server side script in your favourite server side language that receives the city name, looks for that row in the database, and returns the relevant information, such as country and airport.

There are plenty of tutorials available for each step mentioned above.